# scala type erasure when returning generic

Tags: scala

i have a function which returns generics:

```
def getArray(tag: Tags, arr: Option[Array[SearchHit]]
): Array[_ >: CustomerInfoDTO[CustomerApplicationIdDTO] with CustomerIdDTO <: Serializable] = arr match {
    case Some(s) =>
      tag match {
        case GetCustomersInfo =>
          s.map(x => extractCustomerInfo(x.sourceAsString))
        case GetCustomersId =>
          s.map(x => extractCustomerId(x.sourceAsString))
        case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException("Can't match tag")
      }
    case None => throw new NoSuchElementException("Empty Array")
  }
```

so, my problem when i'm trying to match a fuction result:

```
case arr: Array[CustomerInfoDTO[CustomerApplicationIdDTO]] =>
```

i'm getting a warning "non-variable type argument CustomerApplicationIdDTO in type pattern Array[CustomerInfoDTO[CustomerApplicationIdDTO]] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure"

Is it means, that in Array[] it possible to get array of any type? So i have readed about ClassTag and TypeTag, but misunderstood how to use it in my case. So can you help me? how to handle this warning?

Answer (score 0):

Note that it's complaining about `CustomerApplicationIdDTO`, not `CustomerInfoDTO`: `Array` is unique in that you can actually test for `Array[CustomerInfoDTO[_]]`, so `case arr: Array[CustomerInfoDTO[_]] =>` won't give a warning.

But even if you intended to say "this function returns either an `Array[CustomerInfoDTO[CustomerApplicationIdDTO]]` or an `Array[CustomerIdDTO]`", that's not what it does; their supertypes (up to `Serializable` can also be there, in particular this function is allowed to return an `Array[CustomerInfoDTO[_]]`. Since pattern matching can't distinguish between `Array[CustomerInfoDTO[_]]` and `Array[CustomerInfoDTO[CustomerApplicationIdDTO]]`, you get a warning.

You should think what benefit do you actually get from this being a single function instead of two `getCustomerInfoArray` and `getCustomerIdArray` which would be simpler to use.

But if you decide it *is* what you want, your options are:

1. Handle just `case arr: Array[CustomerInfoDTO[_]] =>`.
2. If you are certain you won't get `Array[CustomerInfoDTO[AnythingElse]]` from this function, you can tell that to the compiler using `case arr: Array[CustomerInfoDTO[CustomerApplicationIdDTO]] @unchecked =>` (I think; maybe you need `Array[CustomerInfoDTO[CustomerApplicationIdDTO @unchecked]]`).
3. use `TypeTag`s or `ClassTag`s, as you mention, but this is going to complicate things even more.

Comment: Thanks, I exactly sure that my Array will be Array[CustomerInfoDTO[CustomerApplicationIdDTO]] type, becaues i have a function which returns me CustomerInfoDTO[CustomerApplicationIdDTO] before i convert it to Array, maybe problem in class CustomerInfoDTO[T<CustomerApplication] ?

Comment: Then you can go with solution 2. But again, just having separate functions for these cases may be better.

Comment: Yes, actually i have a working version with 2 different functions, but what if i'm going to need a more endpoints, for example geCustomersName, GetCustomerAddress and etc., so isn't it a more suitable, to use one function whic can returns many results ?

Comment: As a tradeoff, you'd get even more complex type. And what if two of these "endpoints" return the same type; then testing the return value's result won't help. If you actually used the return value as `Array[_ >: ...]`, that wouldn't be a problem, but you don't.